# Is it possible to view files on an SD card encrypted with Gallery-vault on a computer?

Tags: gallery-vault

I assume the answer is no but just wanted to check. I had some files/ photos etc on the Gallery-vault app on my phone -they were saved to my SD card. My SD card has been lost/ possibly stolen and I just wanted to check if someone could access these files in any way?

Answer (score 1):

No you cant....because in gallery vault they are encrypted..you cant view encrypted files on computer...because you dont have decryption key or code as it present in your phone